# What's the song that is played in episode 11 of One Piece at 21:54?

Tags: one-piece, music

What's the song that is played in episode 11 of One Piece at 21:54?

I have been dying to find out the name to the song, and I really like it.

Answer (score 1):

The song is **Overtaken** (Japanese title: 追いつめられた), and it is recorded as track 13 in [**ONE PIECE MUSIC & SONG Collection 2**](http://vgmdb.net/album/18825).

You can listen to it on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yN1zAsS3hyo) or a sample of the song on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%AF%E3%83%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9-%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF-%E3%82%BD%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B32-TV%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9/dp/B00005HLM2).